# Java Eclipse: class cannot be resolved to a type inheritance

Tags: java, eclipse

I've run into an issue where when I open projects in Eclipse there is something wrong with the visibility of classes across packages.

Example:

```
package.a
   - public abstract class clazz
package.b
   - public abstract class clazzy extends clazz
```

In the above instance clazzy would have an error, where clazz wouldn't available.  If I move clazzy into package.a, and the move it back to package.b everything is fine, but otherwise I can't get eclipse to recognize that clazz exists at all.

EDIT 1:

Yes, I am importing the class.  I also press ctrl-shift-o (import).  If I hand type out the import, eclipse still fails to recognize that clazz exists.  I have not tried importing the entire package, as generally I avoid doing this for a whole variety of reasons.

Edit 2:

When I first open the project (it can already exist in the workspace) with the following imports:

```
import package.a.Clazz;

public abstract clazzy extends Clazz {
...
}
```

Both the import, and the clazz identifier will be underlined in red.

I have received several suggestions to do:

```
import package.a;
```

Which not only does not resolve the issue, but I also would not want to do for a variety pf reasons.

Edit 3:

I should clarify that when I say "move" in the 2nd paragraph, i mean that if I move package.b.clazzy into another package (say package.a, or package.c) eclipse seems to realize it's being stupid and sorts itself out.  If I then move clazzy back into package.b everything is fine from that point on.

This code compiles and runs correctly from that point on.

Comment: Did you import the class before trying to subclass it?

Comment: Are you importing package `a` before trying to inherit from `clazz`?

Comment: Do you get an error or warning message from the import statement?

Comment: Are all packages in the same *project*? If not, you need to add one project to the other's build path.

Comment: All same project.  Please note the second paragraph, where I note that moveing clazzy, and then moving it back resolves the issue.

Comment: Have you tried renaming `package.a`? Just name it `a` or `com.me.a`...

Comment: That's not really any better than just moving the class back and forth as I indicate I am already doing to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4):

I solved that with adding this import:

```
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
```

hope it may help someone :)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem might be a naming issue... `package` is a keyword in Java and should not be used for names of a package, variable, class etc.

Rename your package to `a`. For that you either recreate it or move the content in a new directory named `a` and change the package identifier at the top of the class to `package a`.

Comment: Ah, maybe this was a source of confusion.  I was simply using generic words to indicate that I've run into this in a variety of package name  contexts.  I'm not actually using 'package' or 'clazz' or 'clazzy' in my code.

Comment: @user2757729 Oh ok... In that case ignore this answer please.

Comment: It was a very good impulse though, upvoted you for the good thought.

Answer (score 0):

import the package like this

```
import a.clazz;
```

not as package is th reserved keyword in java

```
import package.a.clazz;
```

add the import in your code to inherit the class

Comment: Thanks, but please see my edits.  I am doing this.  I will add further edits to clarify this point.

Comment: Ah sorry I misread your post.  package.a.clazz is fine, but it's the import which is there when I open the project, and which suffers from this issue in the first place.

Comment: package is your Package name ?

Comment: no, it's a generic.  I've run into this issue several times, regardless of the package names.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to import `package.a.clazz` (why not?) then you need to refer to it via its full name,

```
public abstract class clazzy extends package.a.clazz {
```

But I really don't know why you would want to do that instead of

```
import package.a.clazz;

public abstract class clazzy extends clazz {
```

In fact, the reason why the "move" in Eclipse works is because Eclipse, when it moves `clazzy` to the new package, automatically adds the `import` statement for you.

Also, be careful to use the right case.  In your question, you used all lower case, but in your edits, you started referring to `Clazz` not `clazz`.  Those are different, where only the first (`Clazz`) follows standard conventions.

Comment: I am fine importing package.a.clazz; what I don't want to do is: import package.a.*; which is what several others have recommended.

My reason for that is twofold:
1)  It occludes intent.
2)  It brings a bunch of undeed stuff into the namespace.